# Check whether a value in a list of type IEnumerable<XAtrribute> exist in another list of same type + LINQ to XML

Tags: linq-to-xml, xattribute

How can I check whether a value of `XTclist` exist in `Xrclist`.

`XR` :

```
<result>
 <claims type="Subject">
          <scope_of_claim>Full scope</scope_of_claim>
          <claim_date>02/28/2009</claim_date>
          <claim_age months="1" years="2" />
</claims>
 <claims type="Vehicle">
          <scope_of_claim>Full scope</scope_of_claim>
          <claim_date>12/8/2010</claim_date>
          <claim_age months="1" years="2" />
</claims>
```

`XT`:

```
<result>
   <claims type="Vehicle">
          <scope_of_claim>Full scope</scope_of_claim>
          <claim_date>24/1/2011</claim_date>
          <claim_age months="2" years="0" />
   </claims>
</result>
```

code :

```
var XRclist = XR.Descendants("claims").Attributes("type");
    var xTclist = XT.Descendants("claims").Attributes("type");

         foreach (var c in xTclist)
         {
             if (XRclist.Contains(c.value)) // This line need to be corrected
             {
                Do some thing.
             }
             else
             {
               Do something else.
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the extension method Any:

instead of  `if (XRclist.Contains(c.value))`

use    `if (XRclist.Any(x => x.Value.Equals(c.Value))`